# QuarkusTest does not output log in dev mode but works in test

Tags: java, logging, quarkus

Hello all So running Quarkus with

```java
mvn quarkus:dev
```

does not output any loggin from my tests, however using the test environment

```sh
mvn quarkus:test
```

does output logs. I can't seem to figure out why..

In my pom.xml i have configured the logmanager

```java
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <quarkus.log.level>DEBUG</quarkus.log.level>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
```

and in my application.properties i have

```java
quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."org.hibernate".level=DEBUG
```

In my test i have

```java
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(VillainResourceTest.class);

    @Test
    void testLogg() {
        LOG.debug("asdfasdf");
    }
```

But this only prints in test mode. How do i configure it for dev mode?

Comment: When you are saying `mvn quarkus:dev` does not show the output of the tests, do you mean that you have enabled continuous testing and the output does not show up?
Asking because dev-mode does not run tests by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test output from continuous testing (in dev mode) can be turned on/off by hitting the `o` key in the terminal (when the window with Quarkus is in focus). The logs from tests will get mixed up with logs from the dev mode instance, so it can get a bit confusing.